# iOS7 UITextView auto resize text

Tags: ios, ios7, interface-builder

I have a UITextView inside a storyboard. The text displayed is localised and can vary in length. I'm looking for a way to resize the font size down until the text fits.

The box can't grow in actual height so a reduction in font size is required.

Can't see anything in IB that allows for this. Thought so far which feels ugly is to measure the contentSize.height against the frame.size.height reducing the font size by 1 each time until it fits.

Comment: Are you building for iOS 7? You could look into TextKit which was just release with iOS 7. Not sure if this helps, but I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`UITextView` hasn't such autoscaling mechanism.
There can be different suggestions...
At first (i assume your text is not editable) you can use `UILabel` instead of `UITextView` - it also supports multiline (set `numberOfLines` to 0 in IB) and minimum/maximum font scale for autosizing to fit text.
Another way (and it sounds smarter to me) is to allow scroll in textView.

Comment: Did investigate using a UILabel ( I have similar in the UI) but scrolling makes more sense. So basically no changes needed.